# How to replace multiple urls to one specific url at once?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

In wordpress database We have these thumbs as url links:

1st example:

```
http://thumb-v.xhcdn.com/t/170/1_6933170.jpg
```

2nd example:

```
https://thumb-v.xhcdn.com/t/325/200/3_8168325.jpg
```

Others are similar. There are over 2000+ urls are exist in the database like above. However the entire database have 15000 urls different than these urls. So I don't want to change all of them just the above structured ones.

I'd like to change/replace these multiple urls with one specific url like this:

```
http://example.com/lockedthumb.jpg
```

How to do this? By excel? Or is there any useful wordpress plugin?

As you can see multiple & different urls are starting with this: http://thumb-v.xhcdn.com/t/ or https version. But the rest of it has different numbered folders and jpg filenames.

Comment: So you want to update all the urls in one column to the one as the example.com? Or just some that fit a certain pattern?

Comment: All the urls in database to the one as example. Urls are same to the end of /t/: http://thumb-v.xhcdn.com/t/

Comment: Well, then that's just an update in the database and nothing else.

Comment: But how can I contain all of the different structured urls and force them to change into just one specific url?

Comment: You don't need to do that. If all you want is to change ALL the urls into one specific, why do you need to look at what they are like? If you want you can add a rule for updating the urls ONLY when they are actually NOT NULL. See my answer.

Comment: Because I dont want to change all of them. There are also other urls like http://ci2.pornhub.phncdn.com/videos/201611/29/97601942/original/(m=eGcE8daaaa)4.jpg i dont want to change these ones.

Comment: I think you don't need to give as many details... still, you need to figure out a pattern for this urls that you want to delete. Could it be something like UPDATE table SET url = 'blabla' WHERE url LIKE '%thumb-v%', but you are the only one that can specify what is the condition to be used.

Comment: Refer to this before doing your updates. I have very little practice with WP to help that well, sorry. https://blog.templatetoaster.com/update-old-urls-in-database/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in SQL :

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://thumb-v.xhcdn.com/t/170/1_6933170.jpg', 'http://example.com/lockedthumb.jpg');
```

You have to edit the table name and the field where are saved the data you search.

Best regards

Comment: I think it's a little bit too early to assume how to solve the question... there's not enough information for that.

Comment: As @Rafael said it is too early to reply. Because what Inazo gave is just for only one url replace. I am asking for multiple (like 2000+) urls to change at once.